# MySQL Foreign Keys and Indexes optimization

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have the following three tables :

`users` (about 1000 lines)

```
    user_id | username | email | ....
```

`events` (about 50 000 lines and increasing at ~500 a day)

```
    event_id | e_date | e_location | e_duration | ...
```

and a table to link users to events :

`users_events` :

```
    user_id | event_id
```

I set up foreign keys on table `users_events` to delete lines either when an event or an user is deleted, and therefore I have an index (PRIMARY) on each `user_id` and `event_id` in each table.

I'm having second guesses about this design as it feels silly to have an index on `events.event_id` as it is a unique ID with a cardinality equals to the number of lines.

`events.date` would have a max cardinality of 365 a year, and `events.location` would be capped at around 200, so those feel much more adequate for indexes than `event_id`.

Any suggestions ?

**Example of most used queries :**

*Finding events a user is going to :*

```
    SELECT e.date, e.location FROM events e
    JOIN users_events ue ON ue.event_id = e.event_id
    JOIN users u ON u.user_id = ue.user_id
    WHERE user_id = 'currentuserid'
```

OR

*Finding if an event already exists based on its characteristics :*

```
    SELECT event_id FROM events
    WHERE date='eventdate'
    AND location='eventlocation'
    AND duration='eventduration'
```

Comment: No reason you cannot have multiple indexes, and MySQL will just chose the one it thinks is best for that query. Extra index does mean a slight increase in INSERT times but for most applications that will be minimal compared to the savings in SELECTs. For a join, a unique index is pretty much as good as it can get. Your first query will select a row from users based on user_id (hope you have an index on that), join that to users_events using an index on users_events.user_id, and then join that to events based on an index on events.events_id (hopefully a primary key).

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  And see if your many:many table looks like [this](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Answer (score 0):

You already have indexes on `users.user_id` and `events.event_id` if these columns have been defined as your primary keys.

The `users_events` table has two indexes (either explicitly created by you or automatically created by the foreign key constraint).

The first query only requires from the indexes mentioned above and would not benefit from any other.

The second query would benefit from an additional index on the `events` table.